# What is the two numbers in Mercurial changeset ID?

Tags: mercurial

```
$ hg heads
changeset:   211:746a4ab8b3e3
```

What is `211` and `746a4ab8b3e3` respectively?

When I do `hg revert -r REV`, what should `REV` be?  `211` or `746a4ab8b3e3`, or `211:746a4ab8b3e3`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`211` is the *[local revision number](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RevisionNumber)* and `746a4ab8b3e3` is the *short [Node ID](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Nodeid)*. The *local* revision will [likely] *differ* between repositories for the same Node ID and is not useful to communicate revisions. The form with the `:` is just a way they are commonly represented together for display.

In most cases *either* "revision number" is okay for use with Hg commands. (And the local version is easier to type!) Be warned, though: if someone says to "update to revision 42" then they are either looking at your screen or need to be taught a lesson.

Now go find [an Hg tutorial](http://hginit.com/) ;-)

Comment: Can `REV` take value `211:746a4ab8b3e3` in the OP?

Comment: @user001 "Sort of". It seems to *ignore* the local revision number if the "compound" form is used. So, *in my Hg*, `hg up -r 211:746a4ab8b3e3` is the same as `hg up -r 777:746a4ab8b3e3` but not `hg up -r 211:ABCDABCDABCD`. I am not sure why this "compound" form would be used, though. (Obviously my numbers are different ;-)

Comment: A : indicates a range, so 211:746a4ab8b3e3 indicates the range between changeset 211 and 746a4. This will be only 1 changeset on your repository, but can be any number of changeset on other people’s repositories.

Answer (score 1):

As pst said before 211 is the local revision number.

I'd recommend to have a look at this great [HG INIT Tutorial](http://hginit.com/)

from the following example of HG Init you can see that with each checkin the first changeset number is increased.

> changeset:   1:a52881ed530d tag:         tip user:        Joel Spolsky
>    date:        Mon Feb 08 14:51:18 2010 -0500
>   summary:     Change crunch to smoosh
>
> changeset:   0:c1fb7e7fbe50 user:        Joel Spolsky
>    date:        Mon Feb 08 14:50:08 2010 -0500
>   summary:     Initial version of guacamole recipe